# How to define nodeCategoryProperty function for a Model in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gojs

`nodeCategoryProperty` function expects to have the signature -
`(a: ObjectData, b?: string) => string`, which, IMO, should be `(a: ObjectData, b?: string) => string | void`, as this function should not return anything if it is being used as a setter.

> If the second argument is supplied, the function should modify the node data
> object so that it has that new category name.

https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#nodeCategoryProperty

For the function I have defined -

```js
    const categoryPropertyFunction = (partData: ObjectData, category?: string): string => 
    {
      if (category) partData.type = category;
      else return partData.type;
    };
```

I am getting TypeScript error:

> TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

Comment: "*IMO, should be (a: ObjectData, b?: string) => string | void*" yet it is clearly not, given that you get an error using your assumption. Why not conform to the interface that 1. the documentation gives you 2. seems to correctly match the error you get when you don't use it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of storing the category name as a property of the "d" property on the data object:

```
  const model = . . .;
  model.nodeCategoryProperty = function (obj: go.ObjectData, str?: string): string {
    if (arguments.length > 1) obj.d.category = str;
    return obj.d.category;
  };
```

Note the use of `function` instead of using an arrow function, so that one can check the number of `arguments`.

The same kind of implementation can be used for the other "...Property" functional properties of the **Model** classes.